# arrays and if statements in Java

Tags: java, arrays

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int array [] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    if (array[] < 4) {
        System.out.println(array[] + "is less than 4");
    }
}
```

how do I make this work? I wanna use all the numbers in the array but when I do if(array[] ...) I have to put a number into [].

Comment: use `loops` to traverse array

Comment: What is your intention with a line like `if (array[] < 4)`? That is not valid Java syntax and it's unclear what you expect that to mean. See [Oracle Java Tutorial: Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) to learn how to work with arrays.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to validate each element in the array, you can use a for loop to increment the index:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] < 4) {
        System.out.println(array[i] + " is less than 4");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the @shmosel, you could also use a for each loop:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int array []= {1,2,3,4,5};
    for (int item : array) {
        if (item < 4) {
            System.out.println(item + "is less than 4");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to compare the full array at once which is not valid.

You need to iterate over the array and compare each array element individually.

```
for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++) 
{
   if (array[i] < 4) {
       System.out.println(array[i] + " is less than 4");
   }
}
```

Comment: can you explain what is i? sorry i'm new at this

Comment: @Marti Here's a basic (and possibly oversimplified, but good enough) overview. An array is a bunch of sequential integer variables in memory. The array itself is just a reference to the first variable in that group. Therefore, it is impossible to compute all the elements at once. You have to iterate over each one, like Darren said.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined you array of elements as follows:
[1,2,3,4,5]. In the array, the items are located in positions from 0 to 4, that means that you have:

```
Array[0] = 1
Array[1] = 2
Array[2] = 3
Array[3] = 4
Array[4] = 5
```

You should use a loop that goes from 0 to 4 to access all the elements, for example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int array []= {1,2,3,4,5};
   for(int i=0; i<array.length); i++){
        if(array[i]<4){
            System.out.println(array[i] + " is less than 4");
        }
   }
}
```

This will make 5 iterations and the value of "i" will be incremented by 1 until it reaches the value 5, then the loop will end (the condition is i < array.length). It will produce the output:

```
1 is less than 4
2 is less than 4
3 is less than 4
```

Comment: The code you've provided in your answer has multiple errors.

Comment: Thanks, I edited it and added an explanation at the beginning

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int array []= {1,2,3,4,5};

           for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
           if(array[i]<4){
         System.out.println(myList[i] + " ");
      }
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Array in java zero-index so the first index start with 0, arr[0] this how you access the array using square brackets and the index that you want.

for loop over the array:

```
for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    System.out.println(arr[i]);
}
```

for more reading: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Answer (score 0):

The other people already answered your question. I want to add some additional information. If you want to learn Java, you should get familiar with Java 8. In Java 8 it's:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int array[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    Arrays.stream(array).filter(i -> i < 4).forEach(out -> System.out.println(out + " is less than 4"));
}
```